# Security of port forwarding using UPnP and OS X

Tags: macos, security, vpn, port-forwarding, upnp

I have set up a VPN server in Leopard to allow me to connect to my MBP from my iPhone.

I have used an application called [iVPN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ivpnd/) that is great for setting one up, and I have used [Port Map](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/) to map the relevant ports using UPnP with my router.

I have used a few port scanning websites to try to see how secure my computer currently is, and it seems to be fine, but, my question is, how secure is it leaving ports 500 and 4500 for allowing VPN access?

Just incase there are any questions regarding password complexity etc, it is a strong password and I have PPTP and L2TP enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's a strong password, and no vulnerabilities are found in the services responding on those ports, you should be fine to my knowledge (this applies to most things).